# Header image that extends and "curls" down into content past the left and right margins

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I've searched a while for help on what I'm trying to do, but I have come up short.  I'm a relative newbie so it's entirely possible that I'm using the wrong search terms.  What I'm trying to accomplish is at

[image]

How do get the "wavy" line to extend past the left and right borders of content div (using only css, javascript and html)?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please post your header image as well.

Answer (score 1):

I first started with this:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
.container:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
  top:-25%;
  left:-25%;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 8px 0 black;
     border-bottom:10px solid white;
}
.red {
  position: absolute;
  height: 21%;
  width: 60%;
  right:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: red;
  z-index: 5;

}
.red:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  bottom:-25%;
  background:lightgray;
  border-top:2px solid black;
  box-shadow:inset  0 5px 0 white, inset 0 10px 0 black;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
<div class="extra"></div>
```

---

But then ended with this (due to time constraints). You may want to look into borer-image in order to make the fading possible:

```css
body{background:black;}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:transparent;
  border-right:8px solid white;
  right: -20%;
  top: 17%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.container:after{
 position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 18%;
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
  border-bottom:5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw each element on Adobe Illustrator and view the source. Then use necessary parts for your [HTML5 SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) shape. You will be able to select them and change their style.

Here's how:

1. Draw the image on Illustrator
2. Go to File->Scripts->SaveDocsAsSVG (on Mac OS X, but on Windows it should be similar). Then you will be able to open the file in a text editor and get  elements. I think some other vector graphics programs also allow you to view the source in SVG format.
3. Put the SVG markup in your HTML.

EDIT:

If I misunderstood your question and you want a bitmap image (.png or .gif with a transparent background) to be wider than content and have a part BELOW the content div, you will need to create three layers with different z-index values. Also, the image should be split into two parts - one for front div and other for back div. The div in between will look like entangled by the line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. You want to place an image in a div, but the image i.e. the curvy line should extend outside it, right?
If yes, try this http://jsfiddle.net/9zzjhevy/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/A/m/O/C/a/r/curve-md.png" />
    </div>
</div>

.img-container{
    display: table;
    border: 2px solid;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
}
img{
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

I couldn't use the image you gave so picked random png image.